# How to generate a set of new different files through shell scripting given a certain pattern name?

Tags: bash, shell-script, terminal

How to generate a set of new different files through shell scripting given a certain pattern name?

Said I have this pseudocode:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..5}
do
    ./processing < base.ppm > picture<i>.ppm #2
done
```

How do I execute the command in **#2** as normally executed in a terminal but I want to generate five different output files (picture.ppm) following a pattern like this:

```
picture1.ppm
picture2.ppm
...
pictureN.ppm
```

So basically I want to concatenate the **i** iterated in the loop in the output file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just ${i}

```
./processing < base.ppm > picture${i}.ppm
```

Example

```
$ cat foo
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..5}
do
    echo ./processing base.ppm picture${i}.ppm
done
$ ./foo
./processing base.ppm picture1.ppm
./processing base.ppm picture2.ppm
./processing base.ppm picture3.ppm
./processing base.ppm picture4.ppm
./processing base.ppm picture5.ppm
$
```

Comment: I changed the code as you pointed but it gives the filename **picture{1..4}.ppm**

Comment: I changed the **for i in 'seq 5'** and it generated the files correctly. Why **for i in {1..5}** does not work?

Comment: it is not the correct syntax. bash does not see `{1..4}` as a list

Comment: You're on old version of bash.  `echo $BASH_VERSION` gives 4.3.42(1) here and works fine.  `{1..5}` expansion first appeared in 3.0, see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/bashchanges

Comment: It seems my is outdated. It gives 4.3.11(1)-release. Thanks for the both answers.

Comment: NOT `Just ${i}`, but `Just "${i}"`.  Always double-quote your variables.  e.g.  `./processing base.ppm "picture${i}.ppm"`